Using REST API in Python to run Workflows in Azure Purview
We are trying to use Purview REST APIs to make a user request that should be able to trigger a Purview workflow run. The workflow should trigger whenever the user is trying to update an asset, for example its description.
According to the REST API documentation, we are using the following code:
import requests

url = f"https://XXXXX.purview.azure.com/workflow/userrequests?api-version=2023-10-01-preview"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",   # each time generated
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

body = {
    "operations": [
        {
            "type": "UpdateAsset",
            "payload": {
                "entities": {
                    "typeName": "azure_sql_table",
                    "attributes": {
                        "guid": "f00553c6-7a45-479f-b2fe-f9f6f6f60000",
                        "userDescription": "New description from ADB via workflow API",
                        "qualifiedName": "mssql://XXXXX.database.windows.net/XXXXX/dbo/YYYYY",
                        "name": "YYYYY",
                        "description": "Description field from ADB via workflow API"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "comment": "Thanks!"
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
response.json()

The response we are getting is:
{'error': {'requestId': '3ea14555-aa4c-48e7-b1b6-1d683f39515b',
  'code': 'Workflow.DataCatalogError.InvalidJsonRequestPayload',
  'message': "Invalid Json request payload: '.entities(missing)'"}}

We do not understand what is missing inside "entities". There is a similar issue here.
What are we doing wrong?

What happens when you switch it from entities to simply "entity"?

@EJZ I also tried that but with no success.

After a brief session with Microsoft Purview support team, we managed to find the solution: it's necessary to have a second entities entry inside the first entities entry, and this second entry must be a list of dicts.
import requests

url = f"https://XXXXX.purview.azure.com/workflow/userrequests?api-version=2023-10-01-preview"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",   # each time generated
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

body = {
    "operations": [
        {
            "type": "UpdateAsset",
            "payload": {
                "entities": {
                    "entities": [
                        {
                            "guid": "f00553c6-7a45-479f-b2fe-f9f6f6f60000",
                            "typeName": "azure_sql_table",
                            "attributes": {
                                "userDescription": "New description from ADB via workflow API",
                                "qualifiedName": "mssql://XXXXX.database.windows.net/XXXXX/dbo/YYYYY",
                                "name": "YYYYY",
                                "description": "Description field from ADB via workflow API"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "comment": "Thanks!"
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
response.json()


Could you try with this body?
body = {
   "operations":[
      {
         "type":"UpdateAsset",
         "payload":{
            "entities":{
               "UPDATE":[
                  {
                     "typeName":"azure_sql_table",
                     "attributes":{
                        "guid":"f00553c6-7a45-479f-b2fe-f9f6f6f60000",
                        "userDescription":"New description from ADB via workflow API",
                        "qualifiedName":"mssql://XXXXX.database.windows.net/XXXXX/dbo/YYYYY",
                        "name":"YYYYY",
                        "description":"Description field from ADB via workflow API"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "comment":"Thanks!"
}


Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I already tried that option but I get the same result.

At github you can follow same question (I think you created there as well): https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/36234

Yes it was me, I also tried using the Azure SDK for Python but getting the same error.

The documentation is a little complicated but I'm primarily referring to the
bulk create or update documentation which defines the data type for "entities" as an array. Could you humor me and try:
body = {
    "operations": [
        {
            "type": "UpdateAsset",
            "payload": {
                "entities": [
                        {
                        "typeName": "azure_sql_table",
                        "attributes": {
                            "guid": "f00553c6-7a45-479f-b2fe-f9f6f6f60000",
                            "userDescription": "New description from ADB via workflow API",
                            "qualifiedName": "mssql://XXXXX.database.windows.net/XXXXX/dbo/YYYYY",
                            "name": "YYYYY",
                            "description": "Description field from ADB via workflow API"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "comment": "Thanks!"
}

I tried to find a reference to the entities expected data type in the UserRequests api docs, but their details only extend to the operations array. For specific types of operations, the docs for those specific operations, I figure, are of better assistance. So I think the first link above, to the bulk update docs where entities are defined as an array, should be helpful.

Hi Jay, I tried to use that API reference as well, I scrolled through many of them. However, with it does not seem to expect square brackets since I get the error {'error': {'code': 'Workflow.DecodingFailure',   'message': "Invalid value for: body (UpdateAsset).payload.entities(expected '{' got '[' at 'operations[0]')"}}
